# What return type should a Scala method have if it can throw/return errors but has Unit return type?

Tags: scala

So usually when we run a method that can both fail and return a value, we can encode our method return type as `Either[SomeErrorType, ReturnType]`. But many times we're running a method for its side effects, so the return type is `Unit`.

I could of course return an `Either[SomeErrorType, Unit]` but that definitely looks odd.

I could also just return an `Option[SomeErrorType]` but it doesn't really look a lot better (and breaks a possibly existing symmetry with other `Either[SomeErrorType, NonUnitReturnType]`s.

What's your approach in these cases?

1. `def m(): Unit // and implicitly know that exceptions can be thrown?`;
2. `def m(): Either[SomeErrorType, Unit] // this is odd`;
3. `def m(): Option[SomeErrorType] // this is odd, as it makes it look as the return type of`m()`on a successful run is an error code.`
4. Other that I can't think of?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I use `Try[Unit]` for that case.

It encodes that the result of the method either succeeds or fails with some `Exception`, which can be further processed.

- vs `T => Unit` `Try` lifts errors to the application level, encoding in the signature that some error can be expected and allowing the application to handle it as a value.
- vs. `Option[T]` => Option is only able to encode that the operation had a value or not
- vs. `Either[SomeErrorType, Unit]` => `Try` It's easier to work with using monadic constructions.

I've used something like this to implement checks.  (imaginary example)

```
for {
    entity <- receiveEntity // Try[Entity]
    _ <- isRelational(entity)
    _ <- isComplete(entity)
    _ <- isStable(entity)
} yield entity
```

where each check is of the form: `Entity => Try[Unit]`

This will return the `entity` if all checks pass of the first error that failed the check.

Comment: Why? What are the advantages over the other approaches? As it stands this seems like it should be a comment at best.

Comment: @TravisBrown Travis, you're right.  I extended the answer to give a better explanation. Merry Xmas!

Comment: about Either to be easier to work with in monadic constructions, it's worth mentioning that since Scala 2.12 now it's as easy as Try.

Comment: The problem with the Try is that it ties me to Exceptions, even in cases like this where I don't actually have any to show. Of course I could replace my error case classes by an exception hierarchy, but it doesn't look so nice that way.

Comment: @devouredelysium then probably `Either` is your best choice. Maybe using a type alias to make it read better? Like `type Attempt[T] = Either[T,Unit]`

Comment: @devouredelysium when having to use Java libs mixed in the scala code (what happens very often in my ecosystem), I find that `Try` is a better fit as it can naturally encapsulate `Exceptions`.

Answer (score 2):

One more option that hasn't been mentioned yet is `Validated` from [cats](http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html). All the options mentioned so far (`Try`, `Either`, `Option`) are monads, while `Validated` is an applicative functor. In practice this means you can accumulate errors from multiple methods returning `Validated`, and you can do several validations in parallel. This might not be relevant to you, and this is a bit orthogonal to the original question, but I still feel it's worth mentioning in this context.

As for the original question, using `Unit` return type for a side-effecting function is perfectly fine. The fact this function can also return error shouldn't get in your way when you define the "real" (right, successful, etc.) return type. Therefore, if I were to select from your original options, I'd go for `Either[Error, Unit]`. It definitely doesn't look odd to me, and if anyone sees any drawbacks in it, I'd like to know them.